# Retrieve no translations for a single query in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I have a model with the *Translate* behavior attached. I'd like to launch a simple count query so I wouldn't like to join to the translate table. I know I can unload the behavior, and then reload it with the same configuration, but I wonder if there's a cleaner way to do it, like a behavior method or option I can set in the same query.

Example query:

```
$this->addBehavior('Translate', [
    'fields' => ['summary']
]);

...

$active = $this->Questions
    ->find()
    ->where(['Questions.enabled' => true])
    ->count();
```

The returned query is:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*)) AS `count`
FROM questions Questions
  LEFT JOIN question_trans Questions_summary_translation ON
(Questions_summary_translation.model = 'Questions' AND Questions_summary_translation.field = 'summary' AND
Questions_summary_translation.locale = 'es' AND Questions.id = (Questions_summary_translation.foreign_key))
WHERE (Questions.enabled = 1);
```

Comment: How have you identified there to be any problem in the first place? Count queries are being performed on clean query copies, that is with containments (like the ones applied by the translate behavior) removed.

Comment: I have just tested it and can confirm the query launched is taking also the *Translate* model.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. What's your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`)?

Comment: I'm using CakePHP 3.3.9 at the moment. Realize that for the **Translate** behavior to join the translation table the current locale must differ from the default one.

Comment: That is correct, I've tested it like that, and there are no joins being generated for me. Despite the description of `Query::cleanCopy()`, it looks like clearing the containment state has only been [**introduced with 3.4.7**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/4489522d1564a5b2cc58ff4d8f240f55fda2390a), but not necessarily intentionally, and it only happens for containments that are being applied in `beforeFind()`, which happens after the query is being cloned, but before the eager loader is being cloned (which is where the containments might get cleared).

Comment: I'd suggest to open a ticket [**over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues), to me it feels that clearing only half of the containment state is not something that one would expect to happen, and it's definitely not clear from the method description. That being said, there is no option or method to simply disable the behavior that you're experiencing. You could clear the containments in your own `beforeFind` callback, but that's pretty much about it.